# Export italics inside verbatim or code

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In an Org document I type

```
call the /static/ method =something(/$with/, /$param/)=
```

and (thanks to `org-hide-emphasis-markers` set to `t`) it appears as

> call the *static* method `something($with, $param)`

both in graphic mode and `--no-window-system` mode. Just what I want.

But then when I export it to HTML, results

```
call the <i>static</i> method <code>something(/$with/, /$param/)</code>
```

How can I convince the exporter to italicize inside verbatim or code too?

Comment: I think that's a bug in the emphasis marker hiding code. Any character inside the verbatim delimiters is exported as it is. Please report this at `emacs-orgmode@gnu.org`. I haven't tried but this should print italics code: `/=italics monospace=/`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, you mean, actually the exporter works correctly and italic should not be honored in the editor itself? I thought to the point you made on verbatim's behavior, but then I would like to achieve the same with code markup.

Comment: Correct. I think that the exporter's behavior is correct. By "with code markup", if you mean "within source blocks", then I am not aware of how to do that. The only thing I can think there is you tweak that source major mode's faces to do italics. That too would help only if you want to make all keywords italics or something like that (it would apply to everything where that face is applied). Well, that too might work only for HTML exports.

Comment: No, I mean inline `~code~` instead of `=verbatim=`.

Comment: btw my first suggestion `/=italics monospace=/` doesn't work.

Comment: I have [posed this question on emacs-orgmode list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/101515).